# FastReports: Adding Objects to other than OverlayBand

Tags: vb.net, delphi, fastreport

I am writing a FastReport **from code** (not using the designer), the report eventually to be exported to a file.

If I export the report created from code to a `.fpx` - a report preview file, the file's bands do not appear when opened in "Edit Page" mode via the designer (though the bands' contents - e.g. data - does). The report is rendered, correctly - the content is where it needs to be. The only band that is present is the `OverlayBand` - not explicitly created by me in the code.

If I add band objects through code - for instance, a `DataBand` object - how do I ensure the added objects are: [1] added to the report, itself; and [2] not absorbed (?) by - or, added to - the `OverlayBand` object.

I consulted the scant documentation and have not found an answer. I am *not* looking for you to code the report for me. My thought is that I am missing a critical piece of the creation-from-code puzzle, e.g. the addition of further *layers* (not bands) to the report page.

Currently, I am instantiating a report:

```
Dim rptReport As New Report
Dim rptPage As New ReportPage
rptReport.Pages.Add(prtPage)
```

Further objects are then added to the the `rptPage.Bands` using:

```
' Pseudo-code:
rptPage.Bands.Add(aBandObject)
```

Must I explicitly add layers to the page before I can begin adding bands to it? My thought is that there is code that must enable the addition of bands to layers other than the overlay band, i.e.:

```
Dim rptReport As New Report
Dim rptPage As New ReportPage
rptReport.Pages.Add(prtPage)

' CODE INSERTED HERE: rptPage.Objects.Add(Bands) (Pseudo-code)
```

Again, if you are able to point in the right direction, I am okay with that; however, I have consulted the forums and documentation and am unable to find an answer - hence my asking, here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, the issue does not appear to arise from the code.

When saved as a **.fpx file** and then opened in "Edit Mode", it remains true that the bands disappear; however, if I run `rptObject.Design()` and open the report that way, the bands appear as they should.

The problem appears to arise from saving the file as a .fpx, the "preview" file (as opposed to .frx)